# Is there any option to have one common vuetify rule for two text fields

Tags: vuetify.js

I have to fill either text-field-1 or text-field-2 or both In a form and I should be able to proceed with save

I tried having a flag variable but I that results in clicking on text-field-1 or text-field-2 to activate the save button

Comment: Hi Charan, could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed property according to your need here is the basic example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    nameRule: [
      v => !!v || 'Name is required',
      v => (v && v.length <= 10) || 'Name must be less than 10 characters',
    ],
    
  }),
  computed: {
      nameRules () {
        
       if(this.firstName.length == 0 && this.lastName.length == 0){
         return this.nameRule;
       }
        
        if(this.firstName.length > 0 || this.lastName.length > 0 ){
         return [];
       }
        
      },
  },
  methods: {
    validate () {
      this.$refs.form.validate()
    },
    reset () {
      this.$refs.form.reset()
    },
    resetValidation () {
      this.$refs.form.resetValidation()
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form
      ref="form"
      v-model="valid"
      lazy-validation
    >
      <v-text-field
        v-model="firstName"
        :counter="10"
        :rules="nameRules"
        label="First name"
        
      ></v-text-field>
    
      <v-text-field
        v-model="lastName"
        :counter="10"
        :rules="nameRules"
        label="Last name"
        
      ></v-text-field>
  
    
  
      <v-btn
        :disabled="!valid"
        color="success"
        class="mr-4"
        @click="validate"
      >
        Validate
      </v-btn>
  
      <v-btn
        color="error"
        class="mr-4"
        @click="reset"
      >
        Reset Form
      </v-btn>
  
      <v-btn
        color="warning"
        @click="resetValidation"
      >
        Reset Validation
      </v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```